# Intrinsic inverse to _mm_movemask_epi8

Tags: c, x86, simd, sse, sse4

So first I'll just describe the task:

I need to:

1. Compare two `__m128i`.
2. Somehow do the bitwise and of the result with a certain `uint16_t` value (probably using `_mm_movemask_epi8` first and then just `&`).
3. Do the `blend` of the initial values based on the result of that.

So the problem is as you might've guessed that blend accepts `__m128i` as a mask and I will be having `uint16_t`. So either I need some sort of inverse instruction for `_mm_movemask_epi8` or do something else entirely.

Some points -- I probably cannot change that `uint16_t` value to some other type, it's complicated; I doing that on SSE4.2, so no AVX; there's a similar question here [How to perform the inverse of _mm256_movemask_epi8 (VPMOVMSKB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622212/how-to-perform-the-inverse-of-mm256-movemask-epi8-vpmovmskb) but it's about avx and I'm very inexperienced with this so I cannot adopt the solution.

PS: I might need to do that for arm as well, would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The shorter critical path would be to convert the `uint16_t` to a mask for `_mm_and_si128`, since that can happen in parallel with comparing the __m128i inputs, and avoids a round-trip.  See also [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675) for a list of links, including [Convert 16 bits mask to 16 bytes mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67203617) which has an SSSE3 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `_mm_movemask_epi8` after a vector comparison, which produces `-1` for `true` and `0` for `false`, you'll get a 16-bit integer (assuming SSE only) having the `n`th *bit* set for the `n`th *byte* equal to `-1` in the vector.

The following is the reverse (inverse?) operation.

```
static inline __m128i bitMaskToByteMask16(int m) {
  __m128i sel = _mm_set1_epi64x(0x8040201008040201);
  return _mm_cmpeq_epi8(
    _mm_and_si128(
      _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(m),
        _mm_set_epi64x(0x0101010101010101, 0)),
      sel),
    sel);
}
```

Note that you might want to do a bitwise operation with the vector mask converted from an integer mask, without going back and forth between integer ops and vector ops.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate a bit on the details? For example I am unsure as to why this takes int instead of uint16_t? Also, what does it do exactly and what are those magic values?

Comment: @AndrewS. `int` is `int32_t` on platforms that support intel intrinsics. `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` (`movd`) takes an `int`, so an unnecessary zero extension might happen if you put a `uint16_t`. Also, the high 16 bits of the `int` argument (`m`) is ignored.

Comment: @AndrewS.  The Intel intrinsics guide website ([link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#)) explains in detail what exactly each of those intrinsics do with certain magic-value inputs.

Comment: The part I don't really understand is that -- since the flag I need to do bitwise and with is `uint16_t` -- can I pass it into this function? Or will the result be really wrong after that?

Comment: @AndrewS. I'd say yes, but if you're not sure what exactly `bitMaskToByteMask16` does, you can put arbitrary values as input and see what the output is (with a custom print function, for example).

Comment: Okay, I'm halfway through incorporating that in my algo, but the catch I found is -- is there a way to compare unsigned packed integers with SSE instructions? It seems like there isn't and I'm wondering why?

Comment: @AndrewS. You can compare the *equality* of unsigned integers interpreting them as signed numbers, but if you want, for example, `0xff` (`-1`) to be greater than `0x7f` (`127`), you unfortunately need AVX512. It's not even possible with plain AVX. If you need this kind of operation in your algorithm, I think that's worth a separate question regarding how to do it efficiently with SSE.

Comment: @xiver77 There’re fast SSE2 instructions to compute minimum or maximum of unsigned bytes. `min( a, b ) == a` expression is equal to `a <= b` and is the inverse of `a > b`

Comment: @AndrewS. Maybe you got this solution yourself, but have a look at Soont's comment above. I totally missed that part. In intrinsics, there is `_mm_{min|max}_epu{8|16|32}`, which is applied to 2 *unsigned* integers.

Comment: But how do I then Invert the result?

Comment: Also, @xiver77, what do I change/add, if I need this function also for  __m128 and for __m128d ? If you could extend your answer --  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @AndrewS. Sometimes you don’t need to: use `_mm_andnot_si128` instead of `_mm_and_si128`, flip order of arguments of `_mm_blendv_epi8`. Or if you’re using these vectors for `_mm_movemask_epi8`, flip the bits afterwards with `^ 0xF`. Or if you really need the flipped vector, use `_mm_xor_si128` with `_mm_set1_epi32( -1 )` second argument.

Comment: @AndrewS. To answer your second question, `__m128`, `__m128i`, and `__m128d` are all same `xmm` registers on hardware. Just use a `cast` intrinsic to match the appropriate type. Those casts don't emit an instruction, but they can consume few cycles to move between integer units and float units.

Comment: That said, for example, if you want to do a bitwise and, use `pand` (`_mm_and_si128`) for integers and `andps` (`_mm_and_ps`) for floats, so that you don't need a cast, but sometimes a cast is inevitable.

Comment: @AndrewS. Also, the Intel intrinsics are mostly a wrapper that matches a certain hardware instruction. It's different from usual libraries, and it assumes you have a basic understanding about x86 hardware. It's not much different from writing directly in assembly.